# Checkbox option in Views - Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I currently have built out my new user accounts to indicate what past work experience they have done.

There are quite a few options to choose from, but I have made it a text box. This doesn't work anymore b/c people misspell their past positions. So I would like to make a bunch of checkboxes where they can check which positions they have worked.

I want to make sure I can still search for these items in the Views area on my website. Is this still possible?

Comment: You will have to make it a taxonomy and create a new taxonimy reference field with checkboxes. Then the hard part will be to transfer old data from old field to your new field, you will have to find a way to make their input correspond to your taxonomy choices (i will go automatic on the one well spelled and manually on the other if the volumetry is not too big). And finally drop the old field.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have created new fields within the taxonomy. Then I did an export of the old data and have gone in and updated it with the new fields in relation to the taxonomy that I created. When I try to import those fields back in on the registrant's record, it says "no new users created" and doesn't update the registrant's record. Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: I am using the User Import module.

Comment: I am not famillar with the module user import, but it sounds like you are trying to create accounts instead of updating them.

Comment: Correct, I need to update user accounts. Is there a special process to do this in?